# SQLite3 GUI front-end (FileMaker)?

Tags: sqlite, user-interface, filemaker

Is there any program that can serve as a GUI front end for SQLite3 database?

The general idea is to connect to the database remotely, and administer it in FileMaker-like GUI interface, where the online scripts would have a job of just presenting stuff.

I tried FileMaker with ODBC drivers, but have not been successful. SQLite3 is not directly supported, and I couldn't find another driver or software online. (Please mind that I am not talking about database editor software, but something that would be used as a database "CMS" if you will.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a mac? Try the ODBC from [Actual Technologies](http://www.actualtech.com/) that will work for the most databases out there.

Comment: While the link may contain the answer, it is better to include a summary of the solution within answer itself. Otherwise, the above becomes useless when the link breaks or changes.

Comment: Thank you very much, will try and report back! :-)

Comment: Exact same question I have....but I need it for Windows - does any one know of a solution for Windows?

Comment: For Windows you can use the MySQL connector. Works well too. https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Answer (score 0):

There is a more direct approach, that I like better because ODBC is not fast. For small amounts of data it's ok. Besides that communicating direct with the external database without to much middleware is in my opinion always better.

[MBS](https://www.monkeybreadsoftware.de/) has a very nice plugin, and supports a lot of SQL connections. It works really well and fast. Perhaps you should take a look. I use it a lot, as I've used ODBC a lot in the past.

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Comment: Well, the answer does contain a link, but it is quite clear I think. Filemaker developers will know what a plugin is and the plugin will have a lot of documentation, as does MBS Plugin for Filemaker.